# how can I write this code elegantly in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I write this in django template:
`{% if event.value.place == 'GET' or event.value.place == 'POST' %}`
how can I write this like:
`if event.value.place in ['GET', 'POST']`?
how can I change this code legantly?

Comment: You could create a custom template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/ If the 'GET' and 'POST' refer to the http request method of the current request you don't want to handle that logic in your template. It should be handled in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't arbitrarily define variables in templates, nor use list literals such as `[1,2,3]`.

Either define a variable in your view (like `methods = ['GET','POST']`) and pass it to the template, so you can do `{% if event.value.place in methods %}` or keep your original way, which is okay.